# Python script to copy files from ec2 windows instance to ec2 linux instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have a requirement where I need to create and schedule a python script to copy a few files from windows ec2 instance to linux ec2 instance once the instances are provisioned.

Can you please advice how to accomplish this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EC2 instances are just like normal computers. So, if you had a Windows computer on your desk and a Linux computer beside it, think about how you would copy files between the two computers and you can do the same thing with Amazon EC2.

Frankly, sending files 'to' a computer can be quite difficult due to security limitations and having to have some way of 'sharing' file systems, such as sharing a network drive.

A much easier way would be to have the Windows instance **copy the files to an Amazon S3 bucket**, and then have the Linux instance **download the files from S3**. You can easily copy the files by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

This method avoids all the problems with security, sharing protocols and coping with different operating systems.